# PostGIS / ST_Intersection error GEOSIntersects: TopologyException

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, topology, geos

With PostGIS, I want to generate a new table being the result of the intersection of a table of mixed geometries and a polygonal layer. Here is my attempt. I think this request is valid. But I have an error related to the topology.

```
CREATE TABLE schema.resultat AS
SELECT gid, suivi,ouvrage_type,
source,code,dr,convention, t2.parcelle, t2.section,
ST_Intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom ) as geom 
FROM schema.t1
JOIN schema.t2 on ST_Intersects (t1.geom,t2.geom)


Code:
ERROR: ERREUR:  GEOSIntersects: TopologyException: side location conflict at 872675.09999999998 6823686.2999999998


SQL state: XX000
```

Comment: `ST_Intersection` may produce errors in certain input situations (although this rarely occurs in practice). Is it possible for you to post the geometries which cause the error?

Comment: Yes i am OK for sharing geometries which cause the error. But how I can do that? Thanks.

Comment: Try snap to grid and/or a very small buffer

Comment: If they are not too large, post the WKB here.  Otherwise put them somewhere and post a link.